# How to make a pipe loop in Zsh?

Tags: loops, pipe, zsh

Penz says that the problem could be solved by Multios and coproc features in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244/how-to-make-a-pipe-loop-in-bash).

However, I am unsure about the solution.

I do know that you can use multios as

```
ls -1 > file | less
```

but I have never used such that you have two inputs.

**How can you use these features to have a pipe loop in Zsh?**

Comment: Start by looking at http://chronos.cs.msu.su/zsh-man/zsh_5.html and http://zsh.org/mla/users/1999/msg00619.html

Comment: @Matt: The last link does not work. Could you repaste it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having trouble understanding the questions.

Are you trying to do the following:

```
(ls -1 && file) | less
```

Where && is used for multiple commands on a single line.

Or are you trying to do the following:

```
ls -1 | tee file | less
```

Where tee puts the output into the file and standard out.