# redirect both stdin and stdout

Tags: bash, netcat

I would like to delegate netcat stdin and stdout to a function.

I can do the following to redirect stdout only

```
nc -l -p 1234 | my_function
```

I can do the following to redirect stdin only

```
nc -l -p 1234 < <(my_function)
```

Comment: should be easy to do the wiring with python/perl/ruby, but I guess it's also doable with bash... named pipes perhaps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to redirect stdout of 2nd process back to stdin of 1st process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129276/how-to-redirect-stdout-of-2nd-process-back-to-stdin-of-1st-process)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When my_function is wrapped as an executable form (file), you can use `-e` option of netcat:

```
nc -l -p 1234 -e my_function
```

However if it's a function in bash, starting Bash 4.0 you can use `coproc`:

```
coproc my_function
nc -l -p 1234 <&"${COPROC[0]}" >&"${COPROC[1]}"
```