# Read a file and replace ${1}, ${2}... value with string

Tags: shell

I have a file template.txt and its content is below:

```
param1=${1}
param2=${2}
param3=${3}
```

I want to replace ${1},{2},${3}...${n} string values by elements of scriptParams variable.

The below code, only replaces first line.

```
scrpitParams="test1,test2,test3"

cat template.txt | for param in ${scriptParams} ; do i=$((++i)) ; sed -e "s/\${$i}/$param/" ; done
```

**RESULT:**

```
param1=test1
param2=${2}
param3=${3}
```

**EXPECTED:**

```
param1=test1
param2=test2
param3=test3
```

Note: I don't want to save replaced file, want to use its replaced value.

Comment: `scrpitParams` in your snippet is not an array, plus there is a typo since you probably meant `scriptParams` like in the second line of code.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: he doesn't try to use it as *array*.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I know that, but maybe the OP doesn't - it's just the wrong term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to use an array, use a real array. `sed` is not needed either:

```
$ cat template
param1=${1}
param2=${2}
param3=${3}

$ scriptParams=("test one" "test two" "test three")
$ while read -r l; do for((i=1;i<=${#scriptParams[@]};i++)); do l=${l//\$\{$i\}/${scriptParams[i-1]}}; done; echo "$l"; done < template
param1=test one
param2=test two
param3=test three
```

Comment: I could not use a real array, I am trying to replace SH files custom parameters which are not stored in an array. By the way, your code works for array.

Comment: I have created another array variable and used this method. Please correct the filename above to template.txt

Comment: @korkuteren I am not exactly sure I understand your first comment but I'm glad it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to debug:

```
cat template.txt | for param in ${scriptParams} ; do i=$((++i)) ; echo $i - $param; done

1 - test1,test2,test3
```

Oops..

```
scriptParams="test1 test2 test3"

cat template.txt | for param in ${scriptParams} ; do i=$((++i)) ; echo $i - $param; done

1 - test1
2 - test2
3 - test3
```

Ok, looks better...

```
cat template.txt | for param in ${scriptParams} ; do i=$((++i)) ; sed -e "s/\${$i}/$param/" ; done
param1=test1
param2=${2}
param3=${3}
```

Ooops... so what's the problem? Well, the first `sed` command "eats" all the input. You haven't built a pipeline, where one `sed` command feeding the next... You have three `sed`s trying to read the same input. Obviously the first one processed the whole input.

Ok, let's take a different approach, let's create the arguments for a single `sed` command (note: the `""` is there to force `echo` not to interpret `-e` as an command line switch).

```
sedargs=$(for param in ${scriptParams} ; do i=$((++i)); echo "" -e "s/\${$i}/$param/"; done)
cat template.txt | sed $sedargs

param1=test1
param2=test2
param3=test3
```

That's it. Note that this isn't perfect, you can have all sort of problems if the replace texts are complex (e.g.: contain space).

Let me think how to do this in a better way... (well, the obvious solution which comes to mind is *not* to use a shell script for this task...)

Update:
If you want to build a proper pipeline, here are some solutions: [How to make a pipe loop in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244/how-to-make-a-pipe-loop-in-bash)

Comment: Your code gave error --> sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `-'

Comment: works here, no idea what you're doing. do you have a different template file or `scriptParams`??

Comment: You did it with two line. When I worked your script as below, could not get the expected result.

**Your script:**

`code`scriptParams="test1,test2,test3"
sedargs=$(for param in ${scriptParams} ; do i=$((++i)); echo "" -e "s/\${$i}/$param/"; done) 
cat template.txt | sed $sedargs
`code`


**RESULT:**
param1=test1,test2,test3
param2=${2}
param3=${3}

Comment: no, my script: `scriptParams="test1 test2 test3"`. you can replace `,` with `sed`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with just bash alone:

```
#!/bin/bash
scriptParams=("test1" "test2" "test3")  ## Better store it as arrays.
while read -r line; do
    for i in in "${!scriptParams[@]}"; do  ## Indices of array scriptParams would be populated to i starting at 0.
        line=${line/"\${$((i + 1))}"/"${scriptParams[i]}"}  ## ${var/p/r} replaces patterns (p) with r in the contents of var. Here we also add 1 to the index to fit with the targets.
    done
    echo "<br>$line</br>"
done < template.txt
```

Save it in a script and run `bash script.sh` to get an output like this:

```
<br>param1=test1</br>
<br>param2=test2</br>
<br>param3=test3</br>
```