# Two programs that interact with each other at runtime

Tags: python, bash, shell, pipe, io-redirection

[This question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1411/12205) on the codegolf.SE sandbox is about writing hangman solvers. I want to write a main "game" program that outputs underscores, and takes single alphabets as input; and another program, the "solver", will take the underscores as input and outputs the letters.

I have no previous knowledge on how to do this. I tried the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5129276/3488231) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40244/3488231), but still no luck.

My sample game program in python is as follows:

```py
import sys
s="HANGMAN"
s2=[]
for i in s:
    s2.append('_')
err=0
print ''.join(s2)
sys.stderr.write('debug _______\n')
while err<6 and '_' in s2:
    c=raw_input()
    nomatch=True
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        if s[i]==c:
            s2[i]=c
            nomatch=False
    if nomatch:
        err+=1
    print ''.join(s2)
```

And my sample solver program is as follows:

```py
import sys
raw_input()
sys.stderr.write('debug H\n')
print 'H'
raw_input()
print 'A'
raw_input()
print 'N'
raw_input()
print 'G'
raw_input()
print 'M'
raw_input()
```

Then in my terminal I tried the following:

```
mkfifo fifo
python game.py <fifo | python solver.py >fifo
```

And

```
coproc python game.py
python solver.py <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}
```

And

```
{ python game.py | python solver.py; } >/dev/fd/0
```

All of these give only the first debug message from game.py, and then seems like both programs are waiting for input. What did I do wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: It is waiting, because you keep writing `raw_input`; this will wait for input

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm trying to implement a way such that the output of game.py will be piped into solver.py, and then the output of solver.py will be piped to game.py - that is, the `raw_input()` in solver.py should accept the input from the output of game.py

Comment: Are you determined to run this over the pipe? It might be easier to set it up as a pure Python script, then adapt it to command line use later.

Comment: @jonsharpe I do not know how to do this in a pure python script, which is why I am resolving to pipes. Also, since this will be used in a language agnostic contest, the redirection must be done either on the game side or the shell, but not the solver side. Besides, I have finally solved it. It would be nice if you can give me some pointers on how to do it in pure python though, just so I can understand this language better. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the `mkfifo fifo` method by adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after every `print` statement.